# Cumulative Line chart of date in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax

In creating a PowerBI report for a ticketing system, I need to plot the cumulative lines for issues logged (this can be counted from Creation_Date) and issues resolved (this can be counted from Resolution_Date). How do I go about plotting these 2 lines?

I read on the net, and [this thread](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Cumulative-Line-Chart-Help/m-p/117040/highlight/true#M49392) seemed relevant to what I want to do. But I did not understand how the solution works.

> Firstly, add an index column in your current table.

When I add an index column, it just adds a sequence (1,2,3,4,...). I don't understand how that will be helpful.

Can you help me with this line plotting?

EDIT: I'm not sure, I can use the solution in above mentioned thread as is, because I don't have a numeric column like him. I will have to depend on a Measure to count the issues from Creation and Resolution date.

EDIT 2: In response to @Foxan's answer, here is the screenshot of the sharp drop in the cumulative line

[image: Sharp Drop in cumulative line]

[image: Last few lines of the Creation Date Column]

Even though the data mostly looks sorted, I can't assume it to be be sorted on Creation Date column. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample data for `Issue` table:

[image: issue]

Note that I have some NULL values for `Resolution_Date`.

First, create a table for the `Date` dimension, based on `Creation_Date` and today:

[image: date]

Then, create measures for `Issues Logged` and `Issues Resolved` as follows:

```
Issues Logged = 
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        Issue,
        Issue[Creation_Date] <= MAX('Date'[Date])
    )
) + 0


Issues Resolved = 
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        Issue,
        NOT(ISBLANK(Issue[Resolution_Date])) &&
        Issue[Resolution_Date] <= MAX('Date'[Date])
    )
) + 0
```

Finally, you can create a line chart with `Date` from `Date` dimension and the measures:

[image: results]

Comment: HI @Foxan, thanks. This is exactly what I wanted. Unfortunately PowerBI is on my office desktop. Will only get to try it on Monday. Will let you know how it works out. This looks promising :)

Comment: @ameyazing No rush :) Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi @Foxan, your solution worked. The cumulative line is plotted. But the problem is that there is a sharp drop in the line at the end (Refer edit in original post). I can't figure out why this is so. Another doubt, why is the "+0" required after the COUNTROWS function in both the measures?

Comment: @ameyazing The `Creation_Date` doesn't need to be sorted. Did you use the exact DAX or what changes have you made? The "+0" is to prevent BLANK() returned from the `COUNTROWS` function.

Comment: Yes, I copy-pasted the DAX you provided. Only changed the 'Issue', 'Issue[Creation_Date]' & 'Issue[Resolution_Date]' to those in my table. Also to view the data in PowerBI, I sorted on Creation_Date, yet, I get that odd entry at the end. Don't know if that is causing the problem.

Comment: Do you have empty values in `Creation_Date`? It's hard to pinpoint the problem unless we have a subset of the data (model)..

Comment: Hi @Foxan, your solution worked perfectly. Now I'm stuck at the next step. I've created a new question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47151249/powerbi-how-to-add-slicer-from-a-different-table). If possible, could you have a look?