# Power BI: How to add slicer from a different table?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to plot a cumulative line chart in PowerBI and add some slicers to it. Let me first describe my data.

My data looks as below:
[image: Original Data]

To plot a cumulative chart, I'm creating a new table using below formula:

```
Cumulative = CALENDAR(DATE(2017, 9, 24), DATE(2017, 10, 12))
```

In this new table, I'm adding 2 more columns as below:

```
Issues_Logged = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Sheet1, Sheet1[Creation_Date].[Date] <= Cumulative[Date].[Date])) + 0
Issues_Resolved = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Sheet1, Sheet1[Resolution_Date].[Date] <= Cumulative[Date].[Date] && Sheet1[Resolution] = "Closed")) + 0
```

Now my completed table looks like this:
[image: Completed Table]

Using above approach my cumulative chart plots fine and looks like this:
[image: Cumulative Chart]

The problem I'm facing with this approach is that when I try to add a slicer for Group (to view this data group-wise), the slicer does not take effect. I know the reason is that 2 tables are not related. I can't see how to relate those 2 tables, or whether I need to change my approach altogether.

Can you help me resolve how to get the slicer working in this case?

Note: In future, original data may also include a field "Priority" and I may need to add a slicer for that too. So the approach needs to be scale-able to achieve that. Number of rows in original data is expected to cross 100K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the new fields as `Measures` instead of `Calculated Columns` if you want them to work correctly with other filters.

It is because `Calculated Columns` are calculated during data refresh according to the row it is in, while `Measures` are calculated at run-time and will take into account other contexts like filters applied and user selection.

See the results of `Calculated Columns` vs `Measures` when a filter is applied:

[image: results]

Comment: Hi Foxan, didn't work for me. When I try to create "Issues_logged" field as a measure, I get the following error: "A single value for variaton 'Date' for column 'Date' in table 'Cumulative' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result."

Comment: @ameyazing Please refer to how I create the `measures` in your previous question. I specifically use `MAX` for the case.

Comment: Hi @ameyazing does this help solving the issue after all? If so, you can [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/313506) to positively close the question.

Comment: Hey @Foxan, so sorry for the delay. Yes, it did work for me exactly as expected. Thanks a lot :)